# Javascript: how to make the website walk in clien't side and read client's IP?

Tags: javascript, facebook

I'm making a simple Facebook tool for update status (with token). And since it's free for my friends to use, i'm facing a problem. Facebook seems like always block an account if the requests come from same IP. In this case, my hosting's IP.

How to make the website walk in client's side and read the client's IP to avoid Facebook ban the users who use my tool?

Comment: https://db-ip.com/

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean this? Get users IP and data :) Check snippet for more info :))

```js
$.get("http://ipinfo.io", function(response) {
    console.log("Your data is:", response);
    console.log("Your ip is:", response.ip);
}, "jsonp");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you @Zhenya for the answer. It it also automatically make Facebook read the requests come from my client's IP instead of my hosting's IP?

Comment: @Igniel to be honest, I do not know, I've never encountered such a problem

Comment: It's nice when you get your answer to acknowledge it in the system too so the person that replied to your question can get rewarded for it.